# I need to append the Id after the first step in my stepper "angular"

Tags: angular, routes, rxjs

I need to append the ID of my Item in my stepper after the first step
EXM:
the API call is happening after the first step for initial creating the it returns an Id that I should use in the next steps but I need to navigate without redirect i only want to append the Id to the current URL but not like a query param,

myCurrentRoute/id

I tried this but I don't want it as a query param

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: `
    <!-- Your component template here -->
  `,
})
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  appendIdToCurrentRoute(id: string) {
    // Get the current route snapshot
    const currentRoute = this.route.snapshot;
    const currentQueryParams = { ...currentRoute.queryParams };
    currentQueryParams.id = id;

    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: currentQueryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge', // Keep existing query parameters
      preserveFragment: true, // Preserve existing fragment
      replaceUrl: false, // Do not replace the current URL in the browser history
    };

    // Use the router to navigate with the specified NavigationExtras
    this.router.navigate([], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try making this small change?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: `
    <!-- Your component template here -->
  `,
})
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  appendIdToCurrentRoute(id: string) {
    // Get the current route snapshot
    const currentRoute = this.route.snapshot;
    const currentQueryParams = { ...currentRoute.queryParams };

    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: currentQueryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge', // Keep existing query parameters
      preserveFragment: true, // Preserve existing fragment
      replaceUrl: false, // Do not replace the current URL in the browser history
    };

    // Use the router to navigate with the specified NavigationExtras
    this.router.navigate([id], navigationExtras);
  }
```